# how to debug nested python lines like this: "c = np.sum(np.abs(a-b))"

Tags: python, pdb

I'm using `pdb.set_trace()` to debug.
But I'm confused with such nested things.
When using command 's' in pdb, it steps into `np.sum` directly and `np.abs(a-b)` would be done already.
How to stop inside `np.sum`?

What if the nested line is more complex? How to control the flow in detail?
Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make it two (or more) lines:

```
d = np.abs(a-b)
c = np.sum(d)
```

Comment: Thank u. but Which one is more pythonic? the short line or the complex one?